# Google Glass: How to implement take a note command from Java Starter Project

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I am working on implementing a use case using custom
voice command "take a note" command to get back a response with picture from Glassware.

1. What's the best way to add a AcceptCommands property to Java Stater Project contact in order to enable custom voice command inside NewUserBootstrapper.bootstrapNewUser() ?
   Since Contact class is final, it is not easily extended.
   Will there be updated code in java starter project to use voice command like "Take a note" or "Post an Update" as mentioned in XE8 online documentation?
2. What's your suggestion if we cannot / do not use custom command to get back a picture. Can it be done without using subscription?

Appreciate your help.
Lawrence

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are using the latest version of the Starter Project, or update your pom.xml to use google-api-services-mirror version v1-rev20-1.16.0-rc which has support for Contact.setAcceptCommands(). See https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-java/commit/b7d140bd504643be30ba5d3b36e561e799dd2e61 for the patch that was applied 2 days ago to update to XE8 support, and https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/mirror/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/mirror/model/Contact.html for the latest Contact documentation.
2. I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do when you're talking about using a custom command (or not) to get a picture. The standard way to get a picture from Glass to your Glassware is to establish a Contact that accepts the content type and for people to share it. Can you describe the use-case or flow better in your original post?